# Undefined index even with isset

Tags: php, undefined, isset

although i used `if(isset())` still get

```
 Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\jq\182-186 Users online sample application\users.php
```

here is part of `PHP`  code

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']  , $_POST['action']) || isset($_POST['action'])){

    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
```

EDIT: `|| isset($_POST['action'])` IS needed for part of `jquery` that checks DATABASE every half second.

**jquery**

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.post('users.php', { action : 'list'} , function(data){
        $('#users_online').html(data);
        });


    },500);
```

**so i can't delete it**

Comment: how should i edit it?

Comment: @AliGajani Why is it wrong? `isset()` accepts multiple arguments.

Answer (score 8):

Your test is saying:

- If:

  - user_name is set
  - AND
  - action is set
- OR

  - action is set

What this means is that so long as `action` is set, the test will pass, even if `user_name` is not set, as is clearly the case in your error message.

Just remove that `|| isset($_POST['action'])` bit and it should work fine.

Also, have a +1 for making me realise that all my `isset(...) && isset(...)` chains that I've ever written are superfluous XD

Comment: Hahaha, is that comma separated values working as `&&` wow :D

Comment: It's what the [docs](http://php.net/isset) say. Considering I learned everything I know about PHP from the docs, it's kind of embarrassing that I didn't know this until I looked it up while writing the answer!

Comment: i'm watching **jquery** tutorial onthenewboston and `||` in needed for part of program.in actual program that he's writing it works just fine.btw thanks for answer i need time to think.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Thanks to you as many of us including you, learnt a new side of the isset function today.

Comment: This is the first time I see someone using `isset()` with multiparams, I was so used to have `isset(...) && isset(...)` that I never searched for any different solution. Feel embarrased too

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  when i delete `|| isset($_POST['action'])` `setInterval` will not work.and because of that i"m not able to check `database` every 0.5 second

Comment: 0.5 or 5 is not the case.also browser console shows nothing the odd thing is tutorial uses the same code but not get any error!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to achieve with this part `isset($_POST['user_name']  , $_POST['action'])` it will always be ignored if you have `isset($_POST['action'])`. So if only `action` index is present, this line will be executed `$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];` and it will search for `user_name` index, no matter it does not exist.

You might want to have: `if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['action'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['action'])) {
```

in `||` (or) having one value(`action`) is true all the statement will be true even `user_name` does  empty

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']  , $_POST['action']) || isset($_POST['action'])) {
```